# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre NetBeans y Apache NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, apache-netbeans

Estoy empezando a aprender `Java` en un curso gratuito que encontré de `Oracle`, la cosa es que para el `IDE` en el curso utilizan `Apache NetBeans` pero en internet recomendaban `NetBeans` como `IDE`, y tengo duda de cuál sería mejor para usar o cuál es la diferencia.

Comment: Cual seria mejor es una pregunta basada en opiniones y no llevaria a ningun lado. Usa el que mas te guste o te sea mas comodo...

Comment: Estoy un poco desconectado de Java. Pero donde me quede... Netbeans venía siendo desarrollado por Oracle, creo que su última versión fue la 8.2, compatible con Java8. Salieron nuevas versiones de Java, 9, 10, 11, 12 ...
Y el IDE de Oracle en su versión 8.2, no es compatible. Empezaron a salir las versiones de Apache Netbeans, mas a la par con las versiones de Java. 
El problema vino un poco porque entre la versión 8 de Java y la 9 paso bastante tiempo, muchas empresas se quedaron desarrollando con Java 8, ademas creo que a partir de la 12 o 13 se paga...

Comment: La respuesta corta, si no hay versiones nuevas de Oracle Netbeans... usa este si vas a usar Java 8. Es bastante estable. Usa Apache NetBeans si usas versiones más recientes.

Answer (score 5):

Apache NetBeans y NetBeans son exactamente el mismo IDE.

NetBeans, al igual que Java, era propiedad de Sun Microsystem hasta que Oracle adquirió la compañía en 2010. En el año 2016 Oracle anunció que donaba el código de NetBeans a la fundación Apache para que esta se hiciera cargo de su desarrollo. Esto provocó un *rebranding* del software a su actual nombre **Apache NetBeans**.

Versiones con el nombre **NetBeans**: **3.5** a **8.2**

Versiones con el nombre **Apache NetBeans**: **9** a la actual **12.2** (liberada el 05/12/2020)

Answer (score 4):

Apache Netbeans y Oracle Netbeans no son el mismo IDE aunque sean casi lo mismo.

Oracle Netbeans es el producto que adquirieron al comprar Sun Microsystems. Sun tenía dos productos diseñados especialmente para ser compatibles con su lenguaje estrella [java](/questions/tagged/java), estos eran el Sun Forte y el Sun Netbeans.

Para forte necesitabas una licencia de paga y para NetBeans no, aunque ambos eran software propietario en el caso de NetBeans este era un freeware. Ya sea porque el forte tuvo muy mal marketing o porque tenía falsos beneficios en algún momento netbeans llegó a ser la estrella de los dos, y alcanzó su cumbre aproximadamente entre la versión 5  y la 6 que soportaba edición visual de [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp), y soporte nativo para [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), además de la capacidad de agregar tu propio lenguaje en minutos a partir de una gramática de contexto libre con el plugin [schlieman](https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/schliemann/).
Tanto la edición visual de JSPs como el soporte nativo a Ruby desaparecieron para nunca volver debido a que era un software propietario.

En algún momento Oracle al darse cuenta de que otros IDEs habían rebasado por mucho las capacidades de NetBeans decidieron no seguir invirtiendo en su desarrollo y para deshacerse del IDE lo donaron a la fundación Apache, convirtiéndose desde ese momento en software libre, pero el proceso de donación no fue instantáneo, por ejemplo las primeras versiones de apache NetBeans no tenían soporte para node, mientras que el [netbeans-8.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.2) lo tenía y tenía soporte para una cantidad enorme de plugins.

Este esfuerzo de donación es de años, e implica dejar un software que funcione pero que no tenga ninguna línea de código propietario, ni referencias a librerías propietarias y que las licencias sean open source.

Por un poco más de tiempo el Oracle NetBeans va a tener algunas características extras que no tiene el Apache NetBeans en lo que la comunidad agarra tracción y se impulsa su desarrollo independientemente de Oracle. Otra diferencia es que Apache NetBeans tiene soporte para las versiones más modernas de Java y que su código fuente puedes hallarlo también en github en caso de que desees modificarlo.

Si deseas trabajar con Java en versiones menores a la 9 te recomiendo Oracle NetBeans, si deseas trabajar con versiones más recientes pero de manera estable te recomiendo intentar usar el IDE [coolbeans](/questions/tagged/coolbeans) ahora llamado [openbeans](http://openbeans.org/), que es una distribución creada a partir del Apache NetBeans, particularmente para proyectos maven multi módulo o para desarrollar/mantener algún plugin de NetBeans antiguo.

En resúmen, hacen casi lo mismo pero su código es ligeramente diferente, uno es un freeware y el otro es código libre. Si pretendes desarrollar a futuro con código reciente es mejor usar Apache NetBeans pues en algún momento el **Oracle NetBeans quedará obsoleto** y desaparecerá completamente en cuanto Oracle termine de migrar su código a la fundación apache ( de igual manera no se sabe bien del todo que pasará con el portal de plugins actualmente administrado por Oracle ).