# Configurar JavaFX en Raspberry con NetBeans en remoto

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, raspberry-pi

Quiero desarrollar una aplicación de JavaFX en mi RaspberryPi, usando Netbeans como IDE para poder trabajar en remoto, esto es lo que he hecho:

1.instalado jdk 1.8 con `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

2.instalado la ultima versión de JavaFX Embedded SDK port, cambiando estos archivos:

```
     armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar --> jre/lib/ext/
     armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/arm/* --> jre/lib/arm/
     armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/javafx.platform.properties --> jre/lib/
     armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/javafx.properties --> jre/lib/
     armv6hf-sdk/rt/lib/jfxswt.jar --> jre/lib/
```

3.instalado la libreria librxtx con `sudo apt-get install librxtx-java`

4.En netbeans, he usado como remote JRE path "/usr"

**Output del IDE Log**

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.NullPointerException


    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seembedded.project.Utilities.getTargetOSForRP(Utilities.java:326)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seembedded.project.RemoteBuildPropertiesProvider.createAdditionalProperties(RemoteBuildPropertiesProvider.java:95)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javafx2.project.JFXActionProvider.collectAdditionalBuildProperties(JFXActionProvider.java:294)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javafx2.project.JFXActionProvider.invokeAction(JFXActionProvider.java:185)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.LookupProviderSupport$MergedActionProvider.invokeAction(LookupProviderSupport.java:271)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.ProjectAction$2.run(ProjectAction.java:186)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEvent(Mutex.java:1356)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.ProjectAction.runSequentially(ProjectAction.java:183)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.MainProjectAction$1$1.run(MainProjectAction.java:140)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)    
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**Aplicación**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

**Resultado**
El resultado es que puedo desarrollar la aplicación, copiarla en la raspberry con ssh, y funciona perfectamente.Pero no puedo ejecutarla en remoto, cada vez que le doy a run no aparece nada en la consola y solo sale una notificación con el error "java.lang.NullPointerException"
**Resultado en NetBeans 8.2 y Apache NetBeans 12.0**

```
  
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1  
Causado por: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
C:\Users\manol\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\nbproject\remote-platform-impl.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\manol\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication1\nbproject\remote-platform-impl.xml:102: Remote command failed with exit status 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Al no cargar la clase principal, pensé que podría ser un tema de permisos de archivo en la Raspberry, pero al parecer la carpeta NetBeansProyects tiene todos los permisos

Comment: ¿Has revisado los logs de tu aplicación?

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia padaleiana, pero no sé exactamente que son los logs de la aplicación. Aunque buscando en Internet supongo que serán el OutPut-IDE Log que aparece en la pestaña "View".He editado la pregunta para que se pueda ver mi aplicación, aunque no es más que el Hello World de JavaFX, además del output correspondiente

Comment: No te preocupes, todos fuimos _novatos_ alguna vez, y demostrás esfuerzo :) Pregunta crítica: ¿qué versión de Netbeans estás usando?

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.0. ¿Debería cambiar al Apache NetBeans 12.0?

Answer (score 2):

Según el error que aparece en el output, este es un bug de Netbeans [ya reportado en 2014](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=242628), y que ha sido corregido en el [release 80](http://hg.netbeans.org/releases/rev/4d31c2ce7667).
Con actualizar a una versión más reciente (8.0.2, 8.2), el problema no debería volver a aparecer. Y en caso de que quieras pasarte a Apache Netbeans (versión 9.0 en adelante) ten en cuenta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/415139), en donde se explican las diferencias entre Netbeans y Apache Netbeans: una de las principales es que en la segunda se descontinúan varios plugins (al menos temporalmente, hasta que se complete la transición de código propietario a open source), pero a cambio se consigue compatibilidad con las versiones más recientes de Java.

Comment: Poner enlaces está bien, pero es posible que esos enlaces dejen de funcionar con el tiempo... por favor, cuando vayas a usar enlaces como respuesta, intenta incluir también las partes relevantes de los mismos en tu propia respuesta para asegurar que la respuesta siga siendo válida con el tiempo :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, cambié a la versión 8.2 de Netbeans, porque supongo que es el que tengo que usar ya que Java dejó de dar soporte a JavaFX en la versión 1.8 (Si no me equivoco), de todas maneras he descargado el 12 por si acaso y en los dos me dan el mismo error. La aplicación sigue siendo un Hello World. Lo voy a poner en la pregunta aunque no sé si debería hacer otra.

Comment: @manoleitor97 Realmente deberías formular otra pregunta, ya que esto último es un error distinto.

Comment: Debí ser aún más específica; editado @Benito-B :)